# Ajax call is returning null to controller using obect oriented JS

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am using below js for handling blocking details in my application.I used object oriented JS for implementing the same. but when i save trip details its passing null values to string

```js
function triptable(tablename, isTripIn, addColumnButton, saveButton, result) {
    this.tableName = tablename;
    this.istripin = isTripIn;
    this.dataTable = null;
    this.rowNum = 1;
    this.colNum = 0;
    this.rowCell = 0;
    this.colCell = 0;
    this.iterator = 0;
    this.colsList = [];
    this.tableData = [{}];
    this.oTable = null;
    this.inEditMode = null;
    this.tripDetails = [{}];
    this.addColumnId = addColumnButton;
    this.saveId = saveButton;
    this.init(result);
    this.MasterScheduleId =[];
}

triptable.prototype = {
    init: function (result) {
        this.getSchedules(result);
    },
    getSchedules: function (result) {
        this.colsList = [];
        var returnedData = result;//JSON.parse(result);
        if (returnedData.length > 0) {
            var obj = returnedData[0];
            var s = 1;
            for (var key in obj) {
                var attrName = key;
                var myString = attrName.substr(attrName.indexOf("&") + 1)
                var TripNo = attrName.substr(attrName.indexOf("&") + 1)
                var MasterTripId = attrName.substr(0, attrName.indexOf("&"))
                var tripDetail = {
                    'TripNo': TripNo.toString(),
                    'MasterTripId': MasterTripId
                };
                this.tripDetails.push(tripDetail);
                var attrValue = obj[myString];
                var column = {
                    "mData": key,
                    "mDataProp": key,
                    "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' id= 'chk" + s + "'></input> Trip" + myString,
                    "sType": "string"
                };
                this.colsList.push(column);
                s++;
            }
            results = returnedData;
            var stop = this.colsList[this.colsList.length - 1];
            $('#' + this.tableName + 'ColumnCount').text(this.colsList.length);
            this.colNum = this.colsList.length - 1;

            //var i = this.colsList.indexOf(stop);
            //if (i != -1) {
            //    this.colsList.splice(i, 1);
            //}
            // this.colsList.unshift(stop);
            i = this.colsList.length + 1;
            this.colsList[0].sTitle = this.colsList[0].sTitle.replace("<input type='checkbox' id= 'chk1'></input> Trip", '');
            this.tableData = returnedData;
            this.setTable();
            this.oTable = this.dataTable;
        }
    },
    setTable: function () {
        //Construct the measurement table
        this.dataTable = $('#' + this.tableName).dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bPagination": false,
            "aaData": this.tableData,
            "aoColumns": this.colsList,
            //"scrollY": "220px",
            //"scrollX": false,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "fixedColumns": {
                "leftColumns": 1,
                "rightColumns": 0
            }
        });

        this.bindTableEvents(this);
    },

    saveRow: function (oTable, nRow) {
        var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, this.rowCell, this.colCell, false);
    },

    unbindTableEvents: function (contextData) {
        $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' thead tr th').off('click', contextData.onTableHeaderClicked);
        $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' tbody tr td').off('click', contextData.onTableRowClicked);
        // $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' tbody tr').off('dblclick', contextData.onTableDoubleClicked);
        $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' tbody tr').off('keydown', contextData.onTableKeyDown);
        $('#' + contextData.saveId).off('click', contextData.onTableSaveClicked);
        $('#' + contextData.addColumnId).off('click', contextData.onAddColumnClicked);
    },
    bindTableEvents: function (contextData) {
        contextData.unbindTableEvents(contextData);
        $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' thead tr th').on('click', { context: contextData }, contextData.onTableHeaderClicked);
        $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' tbody tr td').on('click', { context: contextData }, contextData.onTableRowClicked);
        // $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' tbody tr').on('dblclick', { context: contextData }, contextData.onTableDoubleClicked);
        $('#' + contextData.tableName + ' tbody tr').on('keydown', { context: contextData }, contextData.onTableKeyDown);
        $('#' + contextData.saveId).on('click', { context: contextData }, contextData.onTableSaveClicked);
        $('#' + contextData.addColumnId).on('click', { context: contextData }, contextData.onAddColumnClicked);
    },

    onTableHeaderClicked: function (ev) {
        debugger;
        var self = ev.data.context;
        var data = ev.currentTarget.innerText;
        data = data.replace("Trip", "");
        data = data.replace(/\n/g, '').trim();
        //var i = self.tripDetails.indexOf(data);
        //if (i != -1) {
        //    self.TripDetails.splice(i, 1);
        //}
        var removed = _.find(self.tripDetails, function (o) { return o.TripNo == data; });
          self.MasterScheduleId.push(removed.MasterTripId.toString());
        self.colNum = parseInt($(this).index());
        console.log("column_num =" + self.colNum);
        //_.forEach(self.tripDetails, function (product) {
        //debugger;
        //var s = _.findIndex(self.tripDetails, function (o) { return o.TripNo == data; });
        //var item = _.find(self.tripDetails, function (o) { return o.TripNo == data; });

        //});
    },
    onTableRowClicked: function (ev) {
        var self = ev.data.context;
        self.colCell = parseInt($(this).index());
        self.rowCell = parseInt($(this).parent().index());
        console.log("Row_num =" + self.rowCell + "  ,  column_num =" + self.colCell);

    },
    restoreRow: function (oTable, nRow) {

        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

        for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length ; i < iLen ; i++) {
            oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
        }
    },

    editRow: function (oTable, nRow) {

        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        jqTds[this.colCell].innerHTML = '<input type="text" id ="typ" value="' + aData[this.colsList[this.colCell].mData] + '"/>';
    },
    onTableDoubleClicked: function (e) {

        var self = e.data.context;
        e.preventDefault();
        var nRow = $(this)[0];
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        if ($.trim(jqTds[0].innerHTML.substr(0, 6)) != '<input') {
            if (self.inEditMode !== null && self.inEditMode != nRow) {
                /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                self.restoreRow(self.oTable, self.inEditMode);
                self.inEditMode = nRow;
                self.editRow(self.oTable, nRow);

            }
            else {
                /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                self.inEditMode = nRow;
                self.editRow(self.oTable, nRow);
            }
        }
    },
    onTableKeyDown: function (ev) {
        var self = ev.data.context;
        if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            if (self.inEditMode == null)
                alert("Select Row");
            else
                self.saveRow(self.oTable, self.inEditMode);
            self.inEditMode = null;
        }
    },
    onAddColumnClicked: function (ev) {

        var self = ev.data.context;
        self.colsList.splice(self.colNum + 1, 0, { "mDataProp": "newField" + self.iterator, sTitle: "Col-" + self.iterator, sType: "string" });
        //update the result, actual data to be displayed
        for (var iRes = 0; iRes < self.tableData.length ; iRes++) {
            self.tableData[iRes]["newField" + self.iterator] = "data-" + self.iterator;
        }
        //destroy the table
        self.dataTable.fnDestroy();
        $('#' + self.tableName + ' thead tr th').eq(self.colNum).after('<th>Trip-' + self.iterator + '</th>');
        //init again
        self.setTable();
        self.iterator++;
        self.bindTableEvents(self);
    },

    onTableSaveClicked: function (ev) {
        var self = ev.data.context;
        var timeTable = self.tripDetails;
        var masterTrip = self.MasterScheduleId;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ScheduleManagement/Blocking/SaveBlocking",
            dataType: "json",
            data: masterTrip,
            success: function (values) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Below given is the codes using to save tripdetails array

```js
 onTableSaveClicked: function (ev) {
            var self = ev.data.context;
            var timeTable = self.tripDetails;
            var masterTrip = self.MasterScheduleId;//It is array of tripNo
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ScheduleManagement/Blocking/SaveBlocking",
                dataType: "json",
                data: masterTrip,
                success: function (values) {
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
```

And the controller action is

```html
 public JsonResult SaveBlocking(string[] masterTrip)
        {
            int serviceId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ServiceGroupId"]);
            int schedulePlanId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["SchedulePlanID"]);
            //int status = _blockingBL.SaveBlockingSheet(serviceId, schedulePlanId, timeTable);
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Below given codes are using to create objects

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var req = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ScheduleManagement/Blocking/GetBlockingCount/",
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,
        });

        req.done(function (result) {

            var buttons = '';
            var output = JSON.parse(result);
            for (var x = 0; x < output.length; x++) {
                var returnedData = output[x];
                buttons += '   <button type="button" id="' + returnedData.SchecdulePlanId + '" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="getBlocking(' + returnedData.SchecdulePlanId + ')"> ' + returnedData.SchecdulePlanName + '</button>&nbsp;';
            }
            $("#buttonsList").append(buttons);
        });

    });
    function getBlocking(id) {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#throbber') });
        var req = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ScheduleManagement/Blocking/GetBlockingSheet/?id=" + id,
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,
        });

        req.done(function (result) {
            var tripIn = '';
            tripIn = '<table class="table table-bordered trip" id="tripInTable"> </table>';
            $("#tripInTable").remove();
            $("#TripIn").append(tripIn);
            var tripOut = '';
            tripOut = '<table class="table table-bordered trip" id="tripOutTable"> </table>';
            $("#tripOutTable").remove();
            $("#TripOut").append(tripOut);

            var returnedData = JSON.parse(result);
            var tripIn = returnedData.TripInBlocking;
            var tripInTable = new triptable('tripInTable', '0', 'btnAddCol1', 'btnTrip1Save', tripIn);
            if (returnedData.TripOutBlocking != null) {
                var tripOut = returnedData.TripOutBlocking;
                var tripOutTable = new triptable('tripOutTable', '1', 'btnAddCol2', 'btnTrip2Save', tripOut);
            }

            $.unblockUI();
            $("#tripTableContainer").css("display", "block");


        });
    }
</script>
```

Please help me to solve this issue..

Ajax call handling is always very difficult for me. it will be very helpful if any one can suggest a good tutorial for me.

Comment: Where "values" variable is being initialized?

Comment: valus are results getting from ajax call. I haven't initialized it

Comment: var masterTrip = self.MasterScheduleId;
I am getting values up to this line but in controller the values are null

Comment: I got the solution..

used JSON.stringify () before sending data to controller
  data: JSON.stringify(masterTrip),

thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Below code solves my issue

```html
  onTableSaveClicked: function (ev) {
        var self = ev.data.context;
        var timeTable = self.tripDetails;
        var masterTrip = self.MasterScheduleId;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ScheduleManagement/Blocking/SaveBlocking",
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(masterTrip),
            success: function (values) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```